# Can not find post ID with acts_as_votable gem Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-votable

error message:
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
In the postscontroller:

```
def like
    if current_user.voted_for? @post
      @post.unliked_by current_user
    else
      @post.liked_by current_user
    end
end
```

In the _like_link.html.erb:

```
<% vote_text = current_user&.voted_for?(post) ? "unlike" : "Like" %>
<%= button_to vote_text, like_post_path(post), method: :put, remote: :true, class:'like-post' %>
```

In the _likes.html.erb:

```
<%= pluralize(post.get_likes.size, 'Like') %>
```

In the _post.html.erb

```
<div>
  <%= render 'posts/likes', post:@post %>
  <%= render 'posts/like_link', post:@post %>
</div>
```

In the routes

```
resources :posts do
    resources :comments
    member do
      put 'like', to: 'posts#like'
    end
  end
```

I'm trying to put a like button in a blog application with in Rails 7. The user can like a post by clicking this button, but this error poped up after i clicked this button. I'm not sure if I am using this gem corrently, please help me to figure out what did i do wrong. And is there any better way to use this gem? thanks!

Comment: `undefined method id' for nil:NilClass In the postscontroller` — where?

Comment: Do you have any sort of authentication check that ensures that `current_user` is not nil?